# Must declare scalar variable when passing bool

Tags: c#, sqlexception

SQL Server is 2014.  Visual Studio 2017.

I am trying to pass 3 parameters to SQL Server, but getting this error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@Title1Item".'

I've included both the C# and SQL Server side code.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
public DataTable GetInventoryByAssetDescription (string Desc, string DispositionText, bool Title1Item) {

    DataTable myRecords = new DataTable(); 
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection (ConnectionString)) {

    // Specify which stored procedure to use and add a parameter.
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("GetInventoryByAssetDescription", cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@SearchString", Desc);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@DispositionText", DispositionText);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@Title1Item", Title1Item);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter (cmd);
    cn.Open();
    da.Fill (myRecords);
}

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInventoryByAssetDescription] (
    @SearchString varchar(30),
    @DispositionText varchar(200),
    @Title1Item bit
)
```

I expect the 3 parameters to be passed through to the stored procedure, but am getting this error on the da.fill (myRecords) line:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@Title1Item".'

EDIT:  So sorry, guys.  Rusty old programmer here.  Stored procedure code:

```
USE [Inventory]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetInventoryByAssetDescription]    Script Date: 6/4/2019 8:30:15 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInventoryByAssetDescription]
      (
            @SearchString varchar(30),
            @DispositionText varchar(200),
            @Title1Item bit
      )  
AS
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    declare @sql nvarchar (2000)

    select @SearchString=UPPER(@SearchString)
    set @sql = '   select in_eq_ID,
        in_eq_TagNumber as TagNumber,
        Title1Item,
        in_eq_AssetDescription as Description,
        in_eq_ExtendedDescription as ExtendedDescription,
        in_eq_SerialNumber as SerialNumber,
        in_eq_ValuationAmount as TotalValue,
        in_eq_CustodianName as Name,
        in_eq_ComplexBuilding as ShortLocation,
        in_eq_SubLocationCode as ShortRoomNumber,
        in_ca_Categories.in_ca_CategoryName as CategoryName,
        in_eq_DispositionDate as DispositionDate,
        DATEADD (dd, 0, DATEDIFF (dd, 0, in_eq_Equipment.in_eq_AcquisitionDate)) as AcquisitionDate
        from in_eq_Equipment
            LEFT JOIN in_ca_Categories ON in_eq_Equipment.in_eq_CategoryID_fk = in_ca_Categories.in_ca_CategoryID
            where @Title1Item = Title1Item
                AND upper (in_eq_AssetDescription) LIKE upper ('''+ @SearchString + ''')'

        set  @sql=@sql+'   ' + ISNULL(@DispositionText,' ')  + '  order by in_eq_AssetDescription'
        execute (@sql)
        return
end
```

Comment: Can you please paste the whole `GetInventoryByAssetDescription` procedure surely that can't be it

Comment: that *looks* like it should work; random question - is it possible that `Desc` or `DispositionText` is `null` (rather than `""`)? Also : is it possible that you're doing something non-trivial in the sproc such as `EXEC` / `sp_executesql` that is actually the thing surfacing the error?

Comment: Desc is "%1%"
DispositionText is " and ((in_eq_DispositionDate is null) or (in_eq_DispositionDate = ''))"
Title1Item = false

Comment: that `" and ((in_eq_DispositionDate is null) or (in_eq_DispositionDate = ''))"` suggests you're using `EXEC`, which is a: almost certainly a SQL injection hole, and b: is almost certainly why you're seeing this; can you *please* post the full code of `GetInventoryByAssetDescription` - I think the problem is a badly written SP

Comment: That's the whole method except for the return statement:   return myRecords;  }

Comment: @Brian me and RandomCoder are asking for the body of `GetInventoryByAssetDescription`, **the stored procedure** - not the C# method

Comment: Won't let me the post whole stored procedure.  The x at the beginning is actually an @, but stackoverflow is misinterpreting that symbol:

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInventoryByAssetDescription]
      (
            xSearchString varchar(30),
            xDispositionText varchar(200),
            xTitle1Item bit
      )

Comment: @Brian **Post** the whole sql in your post, not in the comments, we are interested to see the sql... Also to help determine if in fact its a SP issue open a new window in ssms and paste this, `EXEC dbo.GetInventoryByAssetDescription '','',0` It might not get anything, but if there's an issue with the proc you will know it's definitely the SP...

Comment: @Brian if you edit the question, you will absolutely be able to post the stored procedure - if you're having difficulty with the code editor, you could post it as a "gist" (https://gist.github.com/) or similar and I'll happily help you edit it into the question here

Comment: Won't let me the post whole stored procedure.  The x at the beginning is actually an @, but stackoverflow is misinterpreting that symbol:

<pre>
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetInventoryByAssetDescription]
      (
            xSearchString varchar(30),
            xDispositionText varchar(200),
            xTitle1Item bit
      )
</pre>

EDIT:  Sorry, guys.  I tried to add code block, but comments can only be edited for 5 minutes. :(

Comment: @Brian again, a: we're not talking about the comment, we're talking about editing *the question* - here's a direct link you can click: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56444348/edit - and b: you're only showing us the *signature* of `GetInventoryByAssetDescription` - we think the problem is in the actual **body** of the stored procedure

Comment: Thanks for your patience, guys.  I have edited the original question to include my complete stored procedure code.  Thanks again, Marc.

Comment: I am using EXEC.  It worked fine in SQL Server 2000.  Having trouble with it now, though.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the datatype BIT in SQLServer as SP parameter, from C# you have to send the values 1 or 0 not true or false so you have to convert bool to int (1 for true and 0 for false)

For example

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@Title1Item", Title1Item ? 1 : 0);
```

or

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@Title1Item", (int)Title1Item);
```

Comment: Still getting the same error with your code change.

Answer (score 0):

Right; the problem is your SP, not the C# code. It **cannot** work in the way written. Parameters and local variables are not "ambient" - they won't be defined inside an `EXEC` or `EXECUTE` block, because they are not scoped in there. In *some cases* there is `sp_executesql` that allows you to *pass through* parameters/values by declaring them and adding them as additional parameters, but in your case this would not be a good idea, because *fundamentally* you are doing something *incredibly* dangerous, i.e. concatenating inputs to create SQL. Your stored procedure right now is a SQL injection hole and could be used to take over your server with minimal effort. If you're OK with having your data stolen and your database destroyed, you could inline/concatenate `@Title1Item` just like you did with the others, but: this is a **terrible idea** and it will hurt you.

Comment: Marc, after such a dire warning, which I do understand and appreciate, I hate to ask, but due to timeline constraints, I have to... how do I inline/concatenate #Title1Item like I did the others?  I don't quite understand what you're saying there.

Comment: I think it would be something like this:    set  @sql=@sql+'   ' + ISNULL (@Title1Item, '0')  + '  and '

Comment: where /@Title1Item = Title1Item this part throws exception /@Title1Item should be outside of quotes like  where' + /@Title1Item + ' = Title1Item

Comment: Thanks, @OlegBondarenko, but you can't have the slash outside of quotes, like this:  where ' + /@Title1Item + ' = Title1Item

Comment: @OlegBondarenko, this seemed to work:  where ' + convert(varchar(1), @Title1Item) + ' = Title1Item

My apologies to all... I wrote the original code close to 20 years ago, and I have not coded in 7 years.  It is all getting pretty fuzzy now.

Comment: @Brain slash was added due to issue with comment here

Comment: @Brian I have added changes for SP definition to my post answer for avoiding misunderstanding  with escaping special symbols in comments

Comment: @Brian FYI, the trick with code in comments is to surround code areas with back-ticks, ` - i.e. `@foo`